# Where can I find a feed Library for C++/MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am looking for a C++ feed library.

Where can I find one?

#### Edit:

I need to be able to access feeds from my MFC application. I would like to have a library that can deal with RSS, audio, video, and whatever else it can fit.

Comment: What sort of feed? RSS? Audio? Video?
What does it have to do with MFC?
More info required I think....

Comment: I need to be able to access the feeds from my MFC application.
i'd like to have a library that can deal with RSS, Audio, Video , the maximum possible.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436/rss-feed-library-for-unmanaged-c). Basically, [Windows RSS Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684701.aspx) will do.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Feedreader-lib](http://code.google.com/p/feed-reader-lib/).  However, it probably has too many dependencies for you.

If you want a list of feed libraries for c++, you could look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459874/recommendations-easy-to-use-low-dependency-c-c-rss-library).  These are the libraries mentioned in the answers there:

- [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html), since RSS feeds are just XML
- [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), same as above
- [xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)
- [Flexible Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/FlexibleParser.aspx) on CodeProject, looks quite good
- [libmrss](http://www.autistici.org/bakunin/libmrss/doc/), hasn't been updated for about a year now

Note that most of these do depend on an external library for downloading the feed, e.g. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/), and the ones that aren't dedicated XML parsers also depend on an external XML parser.